# Display an ActiveStorage Image in Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I am working on
Rails:6.0.3.2 with ActiveStorage and RailsAdmin

I am trying to display my uploaded image on the rails admin side, but only get the no image icon, when I click the icon it takes me to the image, so the image is there. Where have I gone wrong?

My code is as follows:

title.rb

```
class Title < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :book_image
end
```

rails_admin.rb

```
config.model "Title" do
  list do
    configure :book_image, :active_storage
  end

  edit do
    field :book_image, :active_storage
  end
end
```